# Usage of case clause in where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, case, where-clause

I need to add a filter to a stored procedure depending on a dropdowns value

Available values are 0,1,2,3,4,5. @TescilDurum is my parameter.

```
0 = ALL
1 = TescilDurumId IN 4 OR 5
2 = t.ID IS NULL
3 = dncts.RegistrationCode IS NULL
4 = hsm.ID IS NULL AND dncts.RegistrationCode IS NULL IS NOT NULL
5 = hsm.ENSMRN IS NULL
```

So far I tried this from a similar question answer on internet but I'm not sure if it is right thing to do. I'm not sure if this "reverse logic" is correct way to do this. And the order by after it gives an error too...

```
AND 1 =
    CASE WHEN @TescilDurum = 1 AND t.TescilDurumId NOT IN (4,5) THEN 0 
    ELSE CASE WHEN @TescilDurum = 2 AND t.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 0
    ELSE CASE WHEN @TescilDurum = 3 AND hsm.EnsMRN IS NOT NULL THEN 0
    ELSE CASE WHEN @TescilDurum = 4 AND hsm.Id IS NOT NULL AND dncts.RegistrationCode IS NULL THEN 0
    ELSE CASE WHEN @TescilDurum = 5 AND hsm.EnsMRN IS NOT NULL THEN 0
    ELSE 1 END
```

Comment: all places where you use `ELSE CASE` are redundant.  The way the case statement works in SQL each WHEN section is the same as an "elseif" in other languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simplify it:

```
WHERE 
  (CASE 
       WHEN @TescilDurum = 0 THEN 1
       WHEN @TescilDurum = 1 AND TescilDurumId IN (4,5) THEN 1
       WHEN @TescilDurum = 2 AND t.ID IS NULL THEN 1
       WHEN @TescilDurum = 3 AND dncts.RegistrationCode IS NULL THEN 1
       WHEN @TescilDurum = 4 AND hsm.ID IS NULL AND dncts.RegistrationCode IS NOT NULL THEN 1
       WHEN @TescilDurum = 5 AND hsm.ENSMRN IS NULL THEN 1
       ELSE NULL    -- this is default and can be skipped if needed
  END) = 1
```

**EDIT:**

For anyone who is afraid that query above is always `1 = 1`:

`CASE` has default `ELSE NULL` clause so when there is no match before entire statement will return `NULL` and `NULL = 1 => NULL`.

```
DECLARE @v INT = 4;

SELECT 1
WHERE(CASE WHEN @v = 1 THEN 1
           WHEN @v = 2 THEN 1
           WHEN @v = 3 THEN 1
           ELSE NULL    -- this is default and can be skipped if needed
      END) = 1
 -- empty resultset
```

and:

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(ID INT, col VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO #tab
VALUES (1, 'aa'), (2, 'bbb'), (3, NULL), (4, 'aa');

-- DROP DOWN MENU
-- 1 all records
-- 2 only those which ID is in (2,3)
-- 3 only those which has col = 'aa'
-- 4 only those which has NULL value in col

DECLARE @variable INT = 3;

SELECT *
FROM #tab
WHERE 
(
  CASE WHEN @variable = 1 THEN 1
       WHEN @variable = 2 AND ID IN (2,3) THEN 1
       WHEN @variable = 3 AND col = 'aa'  THEN 1
       WHEN @variable = 4 AND col IS NULL THEN 1
       ELSE NULL    -- this is default and can be skipped if needed
 END
) = 1
```

Keep in mind that that there is compound condition with `AND` so correct rows will be returned.

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/411403?SelectValue=2)**</kbd>

Comment: Looks neat but gives some errors, "CASE @TescilDurum" for example gives "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected" error. Also some incorrect syntax errors which all look perfectly normal :(

Comment: @lad2025 just a question why don't the logic is directly 1=1 which is what every case is pointing for me?

Comment: @brykneval There is default `ELSE NULL` so NULL = 1 => NULL

Comment: @lad2025 ok, but OP values are 0,1,2...5 and every possible generates 1? is that okay?

Comment: @brykneval Absolutely. Keep in mind that `@TescilDurum` can hold only one value at the time. So user will get only one from `1-5` range

Comment: @lad2025 but what is the purpose of whole CASE there if its either of listed OP values?

Comment: @brykneval it is not every case -- make note of the use of `AND`  where `@TescilDurum` is not 1.  If both sides of the boolean expression with an and are not true it will will not evaluate to true.

Comment: Opinion: While `CASE` has a default `ELSE` value, I find that explicitly adding an `ELSE` clause documents that I thought about handling other conditions and picked a suitable value.

Comment: @HABO Well it depends, default are ok. Anyway updated answer  so [EIBTI principle(Explicit is better than implicit)](http://principles-wiki.net/principles:Rule%20of%20Explicitness?redirect=1) is fulfilled. Or even for more clarity it can be `ELSE 0`